# Unauthorized when query.get() in Parse .NET SDK in worker role.

Tags: parsing, azure, parse-platform

```
     ParseClient.Initialize("id", "key");
     //get the publish instance. 
     string publishInstanceId = msg.Split(':')[1];
     var getPublishQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery("PublishInstance");
     getPublishQuery.GetAsync(publishInstanceId).Wait(); //Exception raised here -    System.AggregateException - Unauthorized.
```

My App ID and Keys are valid and I've checked it thrice. I have also used Master Key, CLient Key as well as .NET key. None of them work.

This code runs in a worker role in Windows Azure Cloud Services.

Im using 1.2.16 version of PArse .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `PublishInstance` set to allow anonymous access? From the looks of the above you're not logging in, so you could be getting that error due to permissions.

Personally I would suggest creating a service account and logging in using that so you can lock your permissions down.

Comment: Yes. There are no ACL's attached to that object I know that is a security threat - but I plan to add that later.